# Multiple buttons based on the same layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

My app consists of GridLayout and multiple buttons (at the moment all of them are ToggleButtons). As the amount of buttons will change based on the user actions, I want to be able to add and remove the buttons in code. Can I create a layout for the button in xml and then create and add them to my GridLayout in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Your getView function of your Adapter can inflate the button from xml.  Generally you check and see if the incoming view is null, and if it is you inflate a new one.

Comment: `Grid**Layout**`, not `GridView`.

Comment: Thanks. I created a new layout file for my button layout and inflate that to the buttons created in Java. 

`ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.togglebutton, null);`

Answer (score 0):

you can do that easily. here's an example:

```
LinearLayout buttonsLayout = (LinearLayout) yourLayout.findViewById(R.id.items_layout);
LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
buttonLayoutParams.setMargins(mMarginsInPixel, 0, mMarginsInPixel, 0);
button.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);

// Adding button to layout
buttonsLayout.addView(button);

// or removing button from layout
buttonsLayout.removeView(button);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what I want. I want to create the layout of the button in xml and then create buttons in Java that use that layout. In your answer it is LinearLayout that is done in xml and buttons have their layout set in Java, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: i didn't completely understand the difference between the two, so i'll just describe what my code does :)

you create your layout in XML. (a linear layout, or whatever you like)
then, in this java code, you find that xml layout by id, create the buttons, and add them to that layout